# Does deleting and creating a table in bigquery renews the quota limit per day?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am creating a data pipeline which writes the data into bigquery table every minute and eventually exceeds the quota limit. Does deleting the table after a few hours and then creating it again will renew the quota limit of that table?

I'm using Python API of bigquery to achieve this task.

Need to update the same table in bigquery without exceeding the quota limit.

Comment: Can you explain what the problem is that you're trying to solve? This sounds a little odd..

Comment: Example use case is: Bigquery table A is created at 12:00 am with quotas and limit. If I drop this table at 02:00 am and recreate the table A. Will the newly created table A will have the renewed quotas and limits? I'm referring to this documentation page for quotas and limits https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas

Comment: Sure, but what's the problem i.e. the business problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I'm creating a realtime dashboard in google data studio which gets the data from bigquery table. This table gets updated with the data every minute thus exhausting the write/load quota per day of the table before the day finishes. So, I'm thinking of deleting the table after a few hours and recreating it again. This is why I'm asking this question that will the quotas/limits/day of the table be renewed if I delete and recreate the table?

Comment: can you please confirm if the quotas and limits gets renewed after deleting and recreating the table with the same name in bigquery as my use case suggested?

Answer (score 1):

As per BQ documents, it imposes an upper-bound limit of 1,000 updates per table per day.

I think you have to "engineer" ways to get around your frequency of updates to a table. There are some very obvious ways around this (which are also pretty standard industry practices) and then there are some tricks. Here is what I can think from top of my head:

1. You can choose to update your target table (overwrite) less frequently.
2. You can a compose a new table name to be valid only for updates coming in for a certain time interval during the day (example: between 2-3 AM, let your pipeline write query results to table `mydataset.my_table_[date]_02_03`). Then, at the time of querying, you can just use wildcard statements like:

   ```
   select count(*) as cnt from `mydataset.my_table_[date]_*`
   ```

   Which is equivalent to:

   ```
   select count(*) as cnt from (
      select * from (
          select * from `mydataset.my_table_[date]_00_01`
      )
      union all
      select * from (
          select * from `mydataset.my_table_[date]_01_02`
      )
      union all 
      ....
   )
   ```

   In this, however, make sure you are always "appending" (not overwriting) data to the table corresponding to the hour of the day. Also, not to forget, you can always take decent advantage of BQ's date partitioned tables to achieve similar results.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Google documentation says otherwise: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas. Daily destination table update limit — 1,000 updates per table per day. Can you share which documentation are you referring to?

Comment: Actually, this answer is not entirely True. I will update my answer to be more precise.

Comment: That's Ok. If I just get the answer to my original question as Yes or No then it would be really helpful.

Comment: Answer to your original question is: No. Deleting a table, and re-creating it and then updating it will still be taken as an operation over the same table. Reason being: TableId will still be the same. As I explained in the answer, you can change the table name to be written for a given interval and will not hit the quota limit this way. At the time of querying, use wildcards.

Comment: Thanks for the answer to my original question.